# For a smooth $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\forall x \in \left< 0,2 \right>, \quad g^2(x) \leq 2 \int_0^2 \left( g^2(y) + (g')^2(y) \right)~dy$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For a smooth function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, prove that
$$\forall x \in \left< 0,2 \right>, \quad g^2(x) \leq 2 \int_0^2 \left( g^2(y) + (g')^2(y) \right)~dy$$
What I've done so far:
Using the equality $g^2(x) = \int_x^{x+1} \left[ g(y) - \int_x^y g'(z)~dz \right]^2 ~dy$ (separately for $x \lt 1$ and $x \gt 1$) and  $(a-b)^2 \leq 2a^2 + 2b^2,$
$$g^2(x) \leq \int_x^{x+1} 2 \left( g^2(y) - \left( \int_x^y g'(z) ~dz \right)^2 \right) ~dy. $$
I'm sure that I should use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to finish the proof, but I can't get it right.
Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the mean value theorem for integrals we have
$$
 \int_0^2 g(y)^2\, dy = 2 g(c)^2
$$
for some $c \in [0, 2]$. Then
$$
 |g(x)^2- g(c)^2| = \left| \int_c^x 2g(y)g'(y) \, dy\right|
\le \int_0^2 \left(g(y)^2 + g'(y)^2 \right) dy
$$
from the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean. It follows that
$$
g(x)^2 \le \frac 12 \int_0^2 g(y)^2\, dy + \int_0^2 \left(g(y)^2 + g'(y)^2 \right) dy
$$
which is stronger than the desired estimate.

Comment: +1. I started with  the MVT for intrgrals but ended up getting a coefficient of $4$ instead of $2$ in the second term.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you! – I started with $g(x)^2 -g(0)^2 = \int_0^x 2g(y)g'(y) dy$ but then had the problem to estimate $g(0)^2$ in terms of the integral :)